# Ubuntu lost all it's hardrive space

Tags: 14.10, disk-usage

I was away from my computer for a while and when I returned it said that it only had 1 GB left.. the time I left it it has 78 GB left and 58 used even though I know I didn’t use that much what is happening.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb5             131G   29G   96G  23% /
none                  4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                  3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 795M  1.2M  794M   1% /run
none                  5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none                  3.9G  1.2M  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none                  100M   80K  100M   1% /run/user
/home/jacob/.Private  131G   29G   96G  23% /home/jacob
/dev/sda1             597G  356G  241G  60% /media/jacob/Programs
/dev/sdb2             1.3T  129G  1.2T  11% /media/jacob/62B05845B0582239
```

Comment: You can see a detailed usage of your Hard Drive using `Disk Usage Analyser`.

Comment: Whats the output of `df -h`?

Comment: How do i find the output of df -h?

Comment: @Hammymcham Open a `Terminal` and type df -h.The output is what you will get after you execute the command.Edit your Question and paste the output here.

Comment: /dev/sdb5             131G   29G   96G  23% /
none                  4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                  3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 795M  1.2M  794M   1% /run
none                  5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none                  3.9G  1.2M  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none                  100M   80K  100M   1% /run/user
/home/jacob/.Private  131G   29G   96G  23% /home/jacob
/dev/sda1             597G  356G  241G  60% /media/jacob/Programs
/dev/sdb2             1.3T  129G  1.2T  11% /media/jacob/62B05845B0582239

Comment: @Hammymcham please edit your question,don't add the output in the comments.

Comment: For what i can see you don't have any problems in matter of storage.You have a lot of free space available.

Comment: @Hammymcham: As per the output of `df -h` everything seems normal to me. Which program is giving you message about disk space and which partition the program is mentioning?

Comment: It was the disk manager when i went to my computer

Comment: I also got a program named bleechbit that cleared over 90 gig for me.. of cach and temperary files

Comment: @Hammymcham: Did you mean `Disk Usage Analyzer` was giving you the alert?

Comment: Yes i did mean that

Comment: In that case,you can run `Disk Usage Analyzer` and locate where is the problem.

Comment: Ive noticed most of the disk loss is in encrypted files.

Comment: What is the path?

Comment: /home/.ecryptfs/jacob/.Private

Comment: I don't know how to proceed as it's not recommended to play with encrypted files,unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: OK that fine i actually fixed it.. A program i had uninstalled was actually still running making it creating cache files..